# What is a good generic strategy for playing as Yarpen?

Tags: the-witcher-adventure-game

In the [Witcher Adventure Game](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/the-witcher-adventure-game/), you can play as one of four characters trying to complete a set of quest. Yarpen is possibly the hardest character to play. He does not have a go to quest deck her can go to. However, I suspect that companions are key to Yapren's success.

*Is there a good generic strategy that can be applied to Yarpen?*

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1484/5318)